# Оптимизация фрагмента в Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-scrollview

У меня существует ScrollView, в котором находится LinearLayout, а вот в нем уже лежат 4 FrameLayout'а. Так вот, эти четыре фрейма заменяются фрагментами с фотографиями, в каждом из которых их по 36 штук. При добавлении фрагмента Scroll очень сильно начинает зависать, и неважно сколько времени пройдет, от "прогрузки" ничего не меняется. Вот в инстаграме в профиле, когда листаешь фотки, ничего не зависает. Я наверное запутал вас, но мне интересно, как там реализован Scroll с большим количеством фотографий или как мне можно оптимизировать свой Scroll ? Вот такой кусок кода на 9 фотографий, в каждом фрагменте их 4. Фрагментов тоже 4. Но скролл лагает даже при 18 фотографиях, меньше не проверял.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_1"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_7"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_2"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_5"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_8"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_6"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ph_9"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А теперь вопрос: А зачем вам 4 фрагмента для отображения фото?

Если вам нужно отобразить какой-либо список есть `RecyclerView`. Это как раз прекрасное решение от компании Google для отображения любых списков, любого размера и любой наполненности.

Вот [здесь](https://devcolibri.com/unit/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-10-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-recyclerview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-tweetsrecyclerview-2/) и [здесь](https://www.fandroid.info/android-uchebnik-sozdanie-recyclerview-cardview-i-menyu-optsij-dlya-elementa-recyclerview/) есть примеры его использования. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135653/recyclerview-%D0%B8-onclick-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83/1135789#1135789) есть простой пример адаптера.

Вообще если вы возьмете приложение и видите в нем скролящийся список в котором больше 10 элементов то с 95% вероятностью это `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Потому что нужно добавить 144 фотографии, но AS жалуется на 80+ вьюх, приходится разделять частями и добавлять фрагментами. Там в одном фрагменте получается  12 рядов, в каждом из которых 3 обязательно квадратных изображения. Я убрал Constraint, лаги пропали, но так же пропала форма квадрата у изображений, не знаю как ее реализовать по-другому.

Comment: Может быть я чего-то не понимаю, но 144  фото для RecyclerView это вообще не о чем. Я добавлял по 500 и это работало плавно. Вопрос в том, что и как вы реализуете. Другой вопрос если у вас не простой список или сетка, то вам придется реально заморочиться с написанием своего кастомного LayoutManager. В том же инстаграме в вкладке подборки фото/видео есть маленькие и есть большие квадратные изображения. Вот это свой кастомный LayoutManager. Но это все еше RecyclerView. а то что вы пытаетесь городить явный и дикий костыль

Comment: Ну по идее сетку реализовать и нужно, только что бы изображения все были квадратные, как в инсте в любом профиле. При открытии они настоящего размера – растягиваются как надо. Но пока мы не открыли, т.е. видим полный список, т.е. так же как в профиле в инсте – они все квадратные

Comment: Ну смотрите: любой список = RecyclerView, тут даже не о чем говорить. А вот открытие и прочее это уже внутреняя работа с RecyclerView. Если вы хотите чтоб изображение по клику увеличивалось прям в списке, тут придется писать свои кастомные LayoutManager-ы или лепить какие-то костыли с макетами. (Хотя ресайклер может отображать разные макеты). Другой вопрос, что есть хорошие решения для открытия нового фрагмента (анимированно и красиво) с вашим фото на весь экран из RecyclerView

Comment: Я ни разу не работал с RecyclerView, но попробую. Только не хочу, чтобы это было просто так. Мне нужно знать, возможно ли там реализовать эту сетку, что бы изображения были обязательно квадртные, по 3 в ряду. Высота ряда = длине одного изображения, но думаю это и так логично было.

Comment: Для простой сетки RecyclerView + GridLayoutManager. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the Это как раз и будет просто квадратная сетка. Количество столбцов вы укажете сами.